# Are generalized eigenvectors orthogonal to eachother if the problem is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Given two real symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, are the eigenvectors of the generalized eigenvalue problem $Ax = \lambda B x$, $x^T B x = 1$ orthogonal?

Put another way, if we denote by $P$ the matrix with the eigenvectors as columns, and $D$ the diagonal matrix that contains the eigenvalues, then $A = B P D P^{-1}$. Does $A$ and $B$ symmetric implies $P^{-1} = P^T$?

What happens if only one matrix of $A$ and $B$ is symmetric but not the other?

What happens if $A$, or $B$, or both are positive-definite as well?

Comment: I am also wondering if the symmetry (of A, B, or both) implies that the eigenvalues are real and not complex as it is the case in general

Comment: Consider $A,B$ with dim(ker($A$)$\cap$ker($B$))$>1$, then any vector in the intersection of the kernels is a solution to your generalized eigenvalue problem for any "eigenvalue". So, no, in general they won't be orthogonal.

Comment: I am not sure to understand... maybe I forgot to specify the constraint $x^T B x = 1$, so that $Bx \neq 0$, and the eigenvectors are not the trivial solution $x = 0$.

Comment: You should definitely specify this :)

Comment: Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal *with respect to the symmetric bilinear form* $B$ (and the proof is entirely parallel to the case where $B=I$), but they are in general not orthogonal to each other with respect to the dot product.

Comment: Ok, so if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric, and if $x$ and $y$ are two generalized eigenvectors then $x^T B y = 0$? Is it true even if $B$ is not symmetric?

Comment: Yes, $x^TBy=0$ if $x$ and $y$ are eigenvectors for *different* eigenvalues. No, this in general is not true if $B$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Thanks, and if $B$ is symmetric, then $P^T B P = I$ which implies $P^-1 = P^T B$. What is the best known resources online on generalized eigendecomposition? I cannot find anything that is not just only about 'standard' eigendecomposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**: consider $2\times 2$ matrices
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&\epsilon\\\epsilon&-1\end{bmatrix},
B=\begin{bmatrix}1&\epsilon\\\epsilon&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $0<\lvert\epsilon\rvert<1$.  Then
$$
B^{-1}A=\frac1{1-\epsilon^2}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-\epsilon\\-\epsilon&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&\epsilon\\\epsilon&-1\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{1-\epsilon^2}
\begin{bmatrix}1-\epsilon^2&2\epsilon\\0&-1-\epsilon^2\end{bmatrix}
$$
which does not have an orthogonal eigenbasis.

Comment: To complete this answer: if $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric matrices, then $P^T P \neq I$, but $P^T B P = I$.